# Navigation Controller in new loaded view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, controller, navigation

I have been trying to figure this out for about a hour and can't seem to find the answer. So basically my app starts, and loads a new view, this view has a tabeview, i understand tableviews, but not navigation controllers as much.

I want this navigation controller to only be loaded with this new view, I don't need it throughout the new app.

I know you can use the app delegate, but I'm still confused if this would work with what I'm trying to accomplish.

If someone could either show me an article about this or just give me some code, that would be amazing.

Thanks very much

Comment: what do you mean? without navigation controller how would you push your views? can you explain bit further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use navigation controller as the root view controller of your app and hide its navigation bar inside views that don't need it.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

To show it again, just call the same method with first parameter set to NO.